# How to pass multiple query parameters in @Query in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using `nativeQuery` in my repository which fetches data from multiple tables using join and it also checks for inputs sent by the user within the query. My `Repository` layer looks something like:

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT e.empname,c.countryName,r.RegionName
  FROM Employee e,Country c, Region r
  WHERE e.countryId=c.countryId
  AND c.regionId=r.regionId
  AND e.employeeId IN (:empIds)
  AND c.countryId IN (:countryIds)
  AND r.regionId IN (:regionIds)", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Collection<Object> findAllActiveUsersNative(CustomFilterRequest request,Pageable pageable);
```

Following is my filter `Class` which are lists of IDs sent from the UI and this list properties of class should be sent to query for further filtering.

```
class CustomFilterRequest{
List<Long> empIds,
List<Long> countryIds,
List<Long> regionIds,
}
```

I know there's `@Param` which can be used for sending individual query parameters but how to send multiple query parameters as in the scenario mentioned above? Is there any way to map properties of this class to query parameters in the `nativeQuery` of `@Query`?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not manadatory for you to pass the entire CustomFilterRequest object as a single parameter, how about the following?

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT e.empname,c.countryName,r.RegionName
  FROM Employee e,Country c, Region r
  WHERE e.countryId=c.countryId
  AND c.regionId=r.regionId
  AND e.employeeId IN :empIds
  AND c.countryId IN :countryIds
  AND r.regionId IN :regionIds", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Collection<Object> findAllActiveUsersNative(
  @Param("empIds") List<Long> empIds,
  @Param("countryIds") List<Long> countryIds,
  @Param("regionIds") List<Long> regionIds,
  Pageable pageable);
```

And then in your service class:

```
repository.findAllActiveUsersNative(
  customFilterRequest.getEmpIds(),
  customFilterRequest.getCountryIds(),
  customFilterRequest.getRegionIds(),
  pageable);
```

Comment: I have thought abut this. But, Is there any way to pass object as query parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SpEL expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query.spel-expressions).

```
  @Query(
      value = "SELECT e.empname,c.countryName,r.RegionName
      FROM Employee e,Country c, Region r
      WHERE e.countryId=c.countryId
      AND c.regionId=r.regionId
      AND e.employeeId IN (:#{#request.empIds})
      AND c.countryId IN (:#{#request.countryIds})
      AND r.regionId IN (:#{#request.regionIds})", 
      nativeQuery = true)
    Collection<Object> findAllActiveUsersNative(CustomFilterRequest request,Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Suppose there's Country Object in the Request Object and countryIDs are within this Country Object.
How to do this using SPEL?

Comment: if country is not type of list object, use request.country.countryIDs.

Comment: And it is possible without using SPeL ?